# how to create report with sqlite and crystal report in .net

Tags: c#, sqlite, crystal-reports

I created windows form application in vs2010 .net c# with sqlite3 .Please any one teach me how to create a report in crystal report. Crystal report is prompting for datbase login.

It is asking for username and password.so please any one tell me how to create database with username and password in sqlite

Answer (score 0):

You can manually load data tables or data sets from your SQlite db and assign them as the data source for the report.

Following link contains step by step approach:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28899/Crystal-Report-with-DataSet-and-DataTable-using-C

On this link, its done with oracle, but you can follow same steps with SQLite.

Hope its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CREATE DATABASE command in SQL to create databases.

Tables can be created with the CREATE TABLE command, and views can be created with the CREATE VIEW command.

It is very important that you learn how to query SQL databases. A good way to do this is with the SELECT command.

Whenever Crystal Reports asks for a login ID and password, you need to type these in, but remember to spell them correctly or it won't let you in at all.